# Hi, so for like 3 weeks i have been trying to allow my floatingActionButton with navigation to be able to allow me to move to the next fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, uinavigationcontroller, android-fragmentactivity

so for like 3 weeks I have been trying to allow my floatingActionButton with navigation to be able to allow me to move to the next fragment in my app, I have tried, researched, everything a beginner coder can do before coming here, so does anyone know why this may be happening. ? Thank you

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ShoppingAdapter.OnClickListener {

    private val sList = shoppingList(100)
    private val gList = groceryList(100)
    private val adapter = ShoppingAdapter(sList, this)
    private lateinit var floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list)

        //Initialize data.
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view1)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            
        }


    }

    //after i click on an item on my list, this action is carried
    override fun onClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item $position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val clickedItem: ShoppingListData = sList[position]
        clickedItem.textView = "clicked"
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)


    }



// allows me to insert content into my app
    fun insertItem(View:View){
        val index: Int = Random.nextInt(8)

        val newItem = ShoppingListData(
            R.drawable.shopping_cart,
        "New Item at position $index",
        )
        sList.add(index, newItem)
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
        View.context
    }

    fun insertItem2(View:View){
        val index: Int = Random.nextInt(8)

        val newItem2 = ShoppingListData2(
            R.drawable.add_shopping,
            "New Item at position $index",
        )
        gList.add(index, newItem2)
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
        View.context
    }
// allows me to remove content in my app
    fun removeItem(View:View){
        val index: Int = Random.nextInt(8)

        sList.removeAt(index)
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
    View.context
    }

    fun removeItem2(View:View) {
        val index: Int = Random.nextInt(8)

        gList.removeAt(index)
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
        View.context
    }
// this allows my shopping list to have a long list with text
    private fun shoppingList(size: Int): ArrayList<ShoppingListData>{
        val list = ArrayList<ShoppingListData>()

        for (i in 0 until size){
            val drawable = when (i % 3){
                0 -> R.drawable.shopping_cart
                else -> R.drawable.shopping_cart
            }
            val item = ShoppingListData(drawable, "Shopping $i")
            list += item
        }
        return list
    }

    private fun groceryList(size: Int): ArrayList<ShoppingListData2>{
        val list = ArrayList<ShoppingListData2>()

        for (i in 0 until size){
            val drawable = when (i % 3){
                0 -> R.drawable.add_shopping
                else -> R.drawable.add_shopping
            }
            val item = ShoppingListData2(drawable, "Shopping $i")
            list += item
        }
        return list
    }

    fun floatingActionButton(View: RecyclerView) {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navHostFragment.navController
        View.context
    }


}
```

activity_main.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

ShoppingListFragment.kt

```
package com.example.netguru_shopping.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import com.example.netguru_shopping.R
import com.example.netguru_shopping.databinding.FragmentShoppingListBinding
import com.example.netguru_shopping.shareviewmodel.SharedViewModel


class ShoppingListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentShoppingListBinding
    private val binding get() = _binding
    private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.list_item, container, false)
        sharedViewModel.shoppingList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {binding.recyclerView1 }
        binding.floatingActionButton
        return binding.root


    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding
    }






}
```

fragment_shopping_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <data>
                <variable
                    name="viewModel"
                    type="com.example.netguru_shopping.MainActivity" />

        </data>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".ui.ShoppingListFragment">




        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_above="@+id/addsubBts"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/addsubBts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/add"
                    android:onClick="insertItem"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_shopping"
                    android:text="@string/add"
                    tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/remove"
                    android:src="@drawable/remove_shopping"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/remove"
                    android:onClick="removeItem"
                    tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />


        </LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="325dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/nextpage"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="floatingActionButton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/arrow" />


</RelativeLayout>
        </layout>
```

ShoppingAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.netguru_shopping.adapter

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.netguru_shopping.R
import com.example.netguru_shopping.model.ShoppingListData

class ShoppingAdapter(
    private val dataset: List<ShoppingListData>,
    private val listener: OnClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder>(){

    inner class ShoppingListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener{
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopText)
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingcart)



        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }

        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            val position: Int = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
            listener.onClick(position)

        }


    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int)
        fun onViewCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)


    }




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShoppingAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return ShoppingListViewHolder(v)

    }




    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShoppingAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.imageResourceId)
        holder.textView.text = item.textView



    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use a FloatingActionButton from your Activity, but the actual FloatingActionButton is only in your ShoppingListFragment's layout. In general, your code looks very mixed up. You are trying to manipulate lists and adapters that belong to ShoppingListFragment from your Activity. Your Activity should not have to know about any specifics of what is in ShoppingListFragment. It should be up to ShoppingListFragment to populate and manipulate its own views.

You have also inflated your Fragment's layout as your activity's layout, so you are not even using navigation or fragments at all in your current code!

The Activity class should be extremely simple because it's simply hosting fragments. I think your entire class should be nothing more than:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
 
}
```

It would have a little more setup to do if you have a NavigationBar to connect to your NavController, or a Toolbar that is shared by all the Fragments, but currently the above is all it should have.

All the work you are doing with lists and RecyclerView, etc., should be in your ShoppingListFragment.

Also, the code you shared doesn't make sense because you override `onViewCreated()` in an Activity. Activities don't have an `onViewCreated()` function to override. That should be giving you a compile error.

As for your specific issue, since the FAB is in your ShoppingListFragment, that's where you should set the click listener. It is easier to set a click listener using a lambda instead of making the Fragment implement OnClickListener and passing `this`. Otherwise, if you have multiple click listeners, you must distinguish which view is being clicked in your `onClick` function.

So in `onViewCreated` in your `ShoppingListFragment`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener() {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigationSomeFragment)
    }
}
```

where `navigationSomeFragment` is the ID of the fragment in your navigation XML that you want to open.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i will look back at my code and fix all the issues you said, hopefully, it works, the reason my code makes no sense is the fact i have been trying every way possible to fix my bug and that by adding code where i think should be but ultimately shouldn't be there.